# jquery hover to change image src show empty image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, hover, src

I have images as my website menu button, and I wanna change the image to another when user hover it or opening the page.

So, I set the hover function in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <div id="menubutton">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" id="bg1">
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/homebutton.png")" alt="home" id="homebutton" />
        </a><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Kitchen")" id="bg2">
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/kitchenbutton.png")" alt="kitchen" id="kitchenbutton" />
        </a><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Stock")" id="bg3" >
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/stockbutton.png")" alt="stock" id="stockbutton" /></a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Shop")" id="bg4" >
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/shopbutton.png")" alt="shoppinglist" id="shopbutton" /></a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Recipe", new { id = 0 })" id="bg5" >
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/recipebutton.png")" alt="recipe" id="recipebutton" /></a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Report")" id="bg6" >
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/reportbutton.png")" alt="report" id="reportbutton" /></a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Notification")" id="bg7" >
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/notificationbutton.png")" alt="notification" id="notificationbutton" /></a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Information", new { id = 0})" id="bg8" >
            <img src="@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/infobutton.png")" alt="info" id="infobutton" /></a>
    </div>

   // Store the old src of the image before hover to reapply after hover
    var oldsrc = "";
    $('#menubutton img').hover(
        function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('id') + '_o';
            oldsrc = $(this).attr('src');
            var newsrc = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString())' + '/Content/New_Layout/' + name + '.png';
            $(this).attr('src', newsrc);
        },
        function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            //var newsrc = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString())' + '/Content/New_Layout/' + name + '.png';
            $(this).attr('src', oldsrc);
        }
    );
```

(Note: I am using the AppSettings to get the correct image path after deploy)

And at every page, I wan to set the image as to highlight the current page user in:

```
 $('#bg4 img').attr('src', '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString() + "/Content/New_Layout/shopbutton_o.png")');
```

Currently, it seems works fine. But if the image hover is triggered several times, the image src will become "" so the image is disappear.

I could not find the cause, so hope can get some help here...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening because you're using the same variable for all `<img>` elements. Instead of sharing one variable between all of them, you should probably store the `oldsrc` in a way that keys on the specific element.

One way to do this is via [the jQuery `.data` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

Code:

```
$('#menubutton img').hover(
    function () {
        var oldsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).data('oldsrc', oldsrc); // Attach data to element

        var name = $(this).attr('id') + '_o';
        var newsrc = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString())'
            + '/Content/New_Layout/' + name + '.png';
        $(this).attr('src', newsrc);
    },
    function () {
        var oldsrc = $(this).data('oldsrc'); // Extract data from element
        $(this).attr('src', oldsrc);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you!! so far so good, and you just introduce me a new jquery method which i never notice before! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

as far as i  understand ur problem you may try this.

```
   // Store the old src of the image before hover to reapply after hover
    var oldsrc = {};
    $('#menubutton img').hover(
        function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('id') + '_o';
            oldsrc[name] = $(this).attr('src');
            var newsrc = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDirectory"].ToString())' + '/Content/New_Layout/' + name + '.png';
            $(this).attr('src', newsrc);
        },
        function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).attr('src', oldsrc[name]);
            delete oldsrc[name];
        }
    );
```

Comment: +1; Good plan too.  Probably does something quite similar under the covers as my answer, tho keys on image name rather than the element.